# How to use android Youtube player to play specific Url?

Tags: android, youtube, android-video-player

The code is working fine  , But i want to play my own url videos not from Youtube and i cant seem to see anywhhere to Parse the Url in the api. help The code is working fine  , But i want to play my own url videos not from Youtube and i cant seem to see anywhhere to Parse the Url in the api. help

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class TruitonYouTubeAPIActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private YouTubePlayer YPlayer;
    private static final String YoutubeDeveloperKey = "AIzaSyAc4bTnZDThXQUh3aTXnGFol4rWiGp6Cz0";
    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey, this);





    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.you_tube_api, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format(
                    "There was an error initializing the YouTubePlayer",
                    errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey, this);
        }
    }

    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
                                        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        YPlayer = player;

 /*
 * Now that this variable YPlayer is global you can access it
 * throughout the activity, and perform all the player actions like
 * play, pause and seeking to a position by code.
 */
        if (!wasRestored) {
           // how do i play my video from this place... NOT FROM YOUTUBE  eg http://campusvibe.co.nf/clear.mp4


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Since you are using Android YouTube API, I think it can play only YouTube videos. Try using VideoView.

Comment: try this tutorials http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-videoview-example/

Answer (score 0):

step to play any you tube video.

**1 create a you tube view in xml file.**

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

**2.inside java file**

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
            YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

        private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

        // YouTube player view
        private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);

            // Initializing video player with developer key
            youTubeView.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
            if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
                errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                String errorMessage = String.format(
                        getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
                Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            if (!wasRestored) {

                // loadVideo() will auto play video
                // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically
                player.loadVideo(YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE);

                // Hiding player controls
                player.setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
                // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
                getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
            }
        }

        private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
            return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your '!wasRestored' condition write follwoing code:

```
yourPlayerObj.loadVideo("videocode");
```

Hope this helps!!